# laravel relation with only get second relation

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, relation

I am getting the relation of an relation like this:

```
Application::select()->where('id', $id)->with('vacancie.company:id,title')->get()
```

now I am getting the full `vacancie` model. How can I only get the company `id` and `title`, excluding the full `vacancie` model?

Comment: because you specify the columns of `company` instead of `vacancy`

Comment: I want only title and id from the company and nothing from the vacancie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i remember correctly, should be something like this:

```
Application::where('id', $id)->with([

    'vacancie' => function($query) {

       $query->select(['id','company_id'])->with([

           'company' => function($query) {
               $query->select(['id','title']);
           }

       ]);

    }
])->get()
```

Comment: You need to edit `$query->select(['company_id'])->with([` and add to the select array `id`. and that needs a `);` at the end of the with. Otherwise its working fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
$details = Application::where('id', $id)->pluck('id','title');
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this code? How does it "exclude the full `vacancie` model"?